# Why Golang MADV_FREE leads to OOM sometimes?

Tags: go, memory, out-of-memory, cgroups

We use the go1.12 and k8s deployment services. In the actual production environment, we have a project that has been OOM until container is killed. Through online survey, it is because Golang MADV_FREE , later we set to MADV_DONTNEED, the problem is sloved.

On the Internet, it said it was MADV_Free means that the system releases memory only when it feels pressure. But memory Alloc happens all the time, Our other services are in the same environment. Why is there no OOM happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I doubt such question is fit for SO as it's unlikely to have short on-point answers, still, let me get a go at it.

The first thing to consider is that the in-kernel OOM killer, when engaged when the kernel finds there's a memory shortage, merely locates a process with the highest memory consumption¹ and brings it down.
(I hope you're talking about the in-kernel OOM killer and not some k8s-specific service or something you've developed in-house.)

Then let's consider the [Go 1.12 release notes](https://go.dev/doc/go1.12) which has switched to using `MADV_FREE`:

> On Linux, the runtime now uses `MADV_FREE` to release unused memory. This is more efficient but *may result in higher reported RSS.*
> The kernel will reclaim the unused data when it is needed.
> To revert to the Go 1.11 behavior (`MADV_DONTNEED`), set the environment variable `GODEBUG=madvdontneed=1`.

(Emphasis mine.)

What this means is that if, say, a program is compiled using Go 1.12 runs during some measure of time under some standard load and then the same program runs during the same measure of time under the same load but with `GODEBUG=madvdontneed=1` setting, the *apparent* consumption of RSS — *as seen from the outside* — will be higher in the first case than in the second.
To reiterate, the number of memory pages actually marked with `madvise(2)` by the Go memory manager will be roughly the same during the both runs, but due to the different semantics of handling the pages freed using both of these ways, the readings of the RSS in use will be different. Not the actual memory usage but only readings of the RSS.

This obviously makes a process which returns memory to the OS using `MADV_FREE` be more likely picked by the OOM killer.

Having said that, I'd advise you to actually look at your problem from a different angle.
Measuring memory consumption of a program written in Go and build by a "stock" Go implementation is not exactly useless but is only useful to catch sort of *obvious* stuff like steady memory growth over multiple GC scan cycles which possibly indicates a memory leak.
To actually assess the real memory usage pattern, you have to use the mertics provided by the Go runtime of the running program.
I have tried to detail the reasons for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73633428/720999).

So I would say, you'd better concentrate on fixing the OOM killer settings or something like this (note that it's possible to make a particular process be immune to the OOM killer).

Also note that you're using a dirt-old *unsupported* version of Go,
and in Go 1.16 the behavior of `madvise` [has been reverted](https://go.dev/doc/go1.16) once again, so it uses `MADV_DONTNEED` again.
Maybe it's a good time to upgrade.

---

¹ It's actually more complex than that as the OOM killer has a set of heuristics which it uses to find "resource hogs", and the memory consumption is just one of the metrics it considers.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. My situation is like this article :
https://www.glean.com/blog/how-we-analyzed-and-fixed-a-golang-memory-leak 
In this article, `The OS, therefore, might not feel the memory pressure and will not free up the memory even though the container might hit the memory limit and get killed. ` ,  I want to know why OS cannot  `might not feel the memory pressure` . And want to know some other go1.12 program is not oom ..

Comment: @xrui, the explanation is given in the sentence immediately preceding your quote: «However, if you go back to how containers are implemented, these are essentially just processes running under separate Cgroups. The OS, therefore, …». "Therefore", is "because of that".

Comment: @xrui, all-in-all, this is not sort of question you can ask on SO anyway because it's not related to _programming_ in Go—please read [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you're interested in interaction between `madvise(MADV_FREE)` and the kernel, you'd better ask it using a dedicated venue—may be even post your question on [LKML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_mailing_list). But please make sure you communicate as much information as possible, at least the kernel version.